# How to bake an animation with modifiers in Blender?

Tags: animation, baking

Im making an animation in blender. The issue is that the animation can't be baked because of the modifiers. I've tried other methods like exporting it in mdd file or skrinkwrap framing but those two don't work as im animating a water mesh. I would love to hear some suggestions like blender addons that can bake all kinds of animation or other methods.

Comment: apply the modifiers and then bake?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean it's not an armature animation, but instead a mesh generated animation?

In that case, the answer is simple: export to Alembic.
It quite literary bakes your mesh "as is" on every frame (or even subframe if you ask for it). It's the go-to format in VFX industry for pretty much everything.

Comment: I found this answer too while experimenting on stuffs. Thanks anyways.